# A simple overlay icon for switching between apps in iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there any way to have a simple icon overlay touching which can toggle between applications on iPad Pro? I am tired swiping four fingers and it causes some irritation on my fingers to swipe on the screen.

Comment: Please read all 3 tags you included. You are asking an off-topic question.  See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Deleted depracated tag